# Bash shell XML to CSV

Tags: xml, bash

I have to parse xml to csv, using xmllint --shell or xmllint --xpath, because I'm not allowed to instal additional packages.

I need firstname and phone in the csv, and nothing else.
I tried this to loop through an xml and parse it to csv file, but the problem is when First name has space (for example Mary Jane) or the phone is missing. Then this kind of solution does not work.

```
for f in $(echo 'cat //FIRSTNAME/text()' | xmllint --shell TEST.xml | sed '1d;$d' | sed 's/-------//') 
do
   echo $f  >> $CSV_FILE_NAMES
done

for i in $(echo 'cat //HOMEPHONE/text()' | xmllint --shell TEST.xml | sed '1d;$d' | sed 's/-------//') 
do
   echo $i  >> $CSV_FILE_PHONES
done


paste -d "," $CSV_FILE_NAMES $CSV_FILE_PHONES >> $CSV
```

Or this combined solution, which places every entity in a new line:

```
for f in $(echo 'cat //FIRSTNAME/text()|//HOMEPHONE/text()' | xmllint --shell TEST.xml | sed '1d;$d' | sed 's/-------//')
do
   echo $f  >> $CSV_FILE 
done
```

```
Mark

9999999999

Jack

8888888888
```

Is there a different way to loop through an xml file?

[XML example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8D3k.png)

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and https://shellcheck.net for validating your script.

Comment: Also you have to check there are CRLF line endings from the xml file.

Comment: 'because I'm not allowed to instal additional packages.'. I wonder what you do have available. e.g. you may have a Perl installation with XML libs, or a Python installation with XML libs, or, or... ?

Answer (score 4):

Given an XML file `file.xml`

```xml
<PEOPLE>
    <PERSON>
        <FIRSTNAME>Alice</FIRSTNAME>
        <HOMEPHONE>555-1212</HOMEPHONE>
    </PERSON>
    <PERSON>
        <FIRSTNAME>Bob</FIRSTNAME>
        <HOMEPHONE>123-4567</HOMEPHONE>
    </PERSON>
</PEOPLE>
```

Then

```sh
echo 'cat (//FIRSTNAME | //HOMEPHONE)/text()' | xmllint --shell file.xml
```

outputs

```
/ >  -------
Alice
 -------
555-1212
 -------
Bob
 -------
123-4567
/ >
```

which is readily parsable with awk, among other tools:

```sh
echo 'cat (//FIRSTNAME | //HOMEPHONE)/text()' | xmllint --shell file.xml | awk '
  NR % 4 == 2 {printf "%s,", $0}
  NR % 4 == 0 {print $0}
'
```

```
Alice,555-1212
Bob,123-4567
```

---

Too bad you can't install other tools: [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) makes it pretty easy to format your output the way you like:

```sh
xmlstarlet sel -t -m //PERSON -v ./FIRSTNAME -o , -v ./HOMEPHONE -n file.xml
```

```
Alice,555-1212
Bob,123-4567
```

Answer (score 3):

In The XML Sample that you have provided, I think it would be simpler to loop over all the ***ZVM_DATA*** then use the XPath *concat* function to concatenate the FIRSTNAME, HOMEPHONE, or any other fields you'd like to include:

```
for index in $(seq $(xmllint --xpath "count(//ZVM_DATA)" test.xml))
do  
    xmllint --xpath "concat(//ZVM_DATA[$index]/FIRSTNAME/text(),',',//ZVM_DATA[$index]/HOMEPHONE/text())" --format test.xml
done
```

It is not the cleanest but unfortunately, *xmllint* supports only Xpath 1.0 otherwise it could be done in one command.

Edit: the result should look like this:

```
Michael ,7800002814
E,7800907671
Ryan,7909355223
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` in a following way

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[<|>]"} /FIRSTNAME/ { v1=$3 } /HOMEPHONE/ { v2=$3 } /\/ZVM_DATA/ {printf "%s, %s\n", v1,  v2}'
```